# No Event object on Scroll Event in MooTools?

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, mootools

I am getting an undefined value for the event object that I think should be available in the callback for the addEvent() function. This is what I'm doing.

```
element.addEvent('scroll', callback(event) {
  console.log(event);
});
// on scroll, event is 'undefined'
```

I tested the same code attaching the callback to the `click` event instead and in that case the event variable was defined as you'd imagine. What am I missing here? My utlimate goal is to stop the normal effect of the scroll, i.e. prevent scrolling, so that I can scroll with an ease function using Fx.Scroll...

Answer (score 2):

It works if you do it right, but it does not pass the event as it's not cancellable.

`callback(event)` makes no sense unless it returns a function that can run at scroll time - else, it's gonna throw due to the block scope after, which will be treated like an object literal....

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/V8fht/

to scroll on an element:

```
document.getElement('div').addEvent('scroll', function(event) {
  console.log('div scroll');
});
```

with

```
div {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

to fire on document scrolling:

```
document.addEvent('scroll', function(event) {
  console.log('scroll document', this); // document
});
```

you can try the native one:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
    return false;
});
```

... it won't stop the scrolling so the event is just a token, really.

@kentaromiura who is a core dev said:

> This behaviour is known and It's documented here: http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element-NativeEvents
>
> The reason to differentiate between 1 and 2 is that 1 is usually used for events that don't have  interesting data like: onload, onscroll, and onresize, or it's more performant. The latter two, for example, are fired frequently.

Comment: I have created an issue on github for it as it _should_ work if I read the code correctly. https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/issues/2607 - though, once again--there is nothing you can do to stop it so it's not useful.